# Why is my car struggling when it gets hot? (breaks, bearings, transmission...?)

Tags: brakes, transmission, troubleshooting, wheel-bearing

If this is TMI, let me know and I'll try to simplify.

I have a 2003 Cadillac CTS with about 205k miles

I recently had the master cylinder and brake booster replaced. When it was finished, the brakes were WAY too sensitive. At first I just thought I needed to become accustomed to it, but after I drove it for a while, it felt like the engine was fighting the brakes. I knew I needed front bearings, so I replaced those, in-case I was feeling that friction. Road noise was greatly reduced, but still not perfect so I replaced the front calipers.  When the car gets hot, it still feels like something is dragging.

During one drive, the car gave me a transmission heat warning. I took it to the shop and they replaced my front brake lines. I also had them do a transmission service and replace the fluid filter.

I still get that dragging feeling when the car gets hot.

I haven't done anything to the rear wheels yet.

What is my next diagnostic step? Would you suspect the rear (and/or parking) brakes, the rear bearings, the transmission...?

Comment: I'd probably measure pedal specs first especially if they replaced the booster. Are the wheels getting hot after driving like a caliper is on? If they are, are all of them hot?

Comment: How hot is "hot"? I've been reluctant to touch the disks because I don't know how hot they might get from normal braking and wouldn't want to blister my delicate little fingers. ;)

Comment: If a caliper is dragging it'll generally heat the rotor enough that it becomes discolored. The wheels normally have some heat to them. If it's so hot you have to pull your hand away them something is wrong.

Comment: I cleaned my wheels today. I'll check them for brake dust after I drive it tomorrow.